# Texture not working properly

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, pbr

I have a PBR material that I got from [here](https://polyhaven.com/a/laminate_floor_02). It's not working as expected. After downloading and putting it into the material node setup (I pressed Ctrl+Shift+T and selected the image textures), this is what is showing on the plane object. [image]

This is the node network. [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Is you model UV unwrapped? If you use the *Texture Coordinate*'s *Generated* output instead of the *UV*, does it work better?

Comment: I needed to unwrap it. It was a simple plane object so I didn't think I needed to do that. How would I use the textured Coordinate's generated output over the UV?

Comment: Generated is generally used with procedural textures, not image textures

Comment: I suppose it is just an image texture cause it’s not procedurally generated. I’m new at this. Thank you both for your help